# Display info by Apache and not tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I've got an application display on Apache with tomcat and I would like to display some info from apache and not tomcat to be more efficient. So I was playing with the `httpd.conf` file, here is a part of my conf file :

```
<VirtualHost info.com:80>
LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
ServerName info.com
ServerRoot "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/Apache2.2"
DocumentRoot "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/Apache2.2/htdocs"
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/app/*.cache.html" no-jk 

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/kerberos-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/appWeb">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/kerberos-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/appWeb/app">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
RewriteLog "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/Apache2.2/logs/apache.rewrite.log" 
JkMount /* appweb

JkUnMount /appWeb/app/*.cache.html appweb
JkUnMount /appWeb/app/resources/flash/* appweb
JkUnMount /appWeb/app/resources/flash_en/* appweb
```

In the log of Apache, there is an error 404 when Apache try to load a file *.cache.html.
The file is present and the path is correct.
What do I do wrong ?

Edit : Thanks for you response Amblyopus. You're right, this is not what I wanted to do. Actually, I was able to solve my problem, by pointing the DocumentRoot directly on the webapps of tomcat, deleting the , and using only JkMount.

```
<VirtualHost info.com:80>
LimitRequestFieldSize 32768
ServerName info.com
ServerRoot "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/Apache2.2"
DocumentRoot "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/kerberos-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps"
RewriteLog "E:/Inetpub/Int/catalina_int/Apache2.2/logs/apache.rewrite.log" 

JkMount /appWeb/app/*.jsp appweb 
     JkMount /appWeb/app/*Service appweb #servlet

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

SetEnvIf expects a regular expression. You now have /app/*.cache.html which basically means it searches for /app, then any number of /, then any character, then cache, then any character and then html. Not really what you wanted right?

You want something like ^/app/.*.cache.html which means the uri must start with /app/, then has any number of characters followed by .cache.html

Best to put some research in regular expressions as many directives expect you to use them.